# He 'used to' call me beast -How to make it a question?

Tags: grammar, questions, wh-questions

A normal sentence:

> He ***made*** a wonderful doll.

We shift a verb to ask a question.

> What *did* he **make?**

That is because the *base verb* is 'make'

But what about this sentence?

> He ***used to*** call me 'the beast.'

The base verb is **not** 'use,' instead we have a phrasal verb 'used to.'

So the question....

> What *did* he **used to** call you? OR  What *did* he **use to** call you?

Comment: See the section titled *Questions*: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past/used-to Logically, *what did he used to* just can't be correct since the auxiliary verb *did* is already enough to tell that what we are talking about is in the past tense.

Comment: @Mic And yet it's correct!

Answer (score 1):

When there is did in the sentence, we say use to (without d) - when there is no did in the sentence, we say used to (with d)

For example,

Did you use to smoke?

I didn't use to go swimming.

Answer (score 1):

Most grammar books will tell you to say:

> What did he use to call you?

for the reason provided by @Michael Rybkin. I agree with this usage, however, even amongst native English speakers, it is not uncommon to hear:

> What did he used to call you?

Whether you say 'use' or 'used', be careful to pronounce it correctly. There are times when the "s" is sounded as 'z', and other times when it is sounded as 'z'. Similarly, there are times when the "d" in "used" is sounded as a 't' and there times when it is sounded as a 'd'. If you look up 'How to pronounce use" in Google, you will find several sites that will assist with this,  Similarly for "How to pronounce used".

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly idiomatic in my ([Central-Atlantic](https://www.daredictionary.com/?region=C%20Atl#entriesList)) AmE dialect:

> What did he used to call you?
>
> What did he used to say?

We do not quite articulate the dental of **used**:

> What did he use' to call you?

Answer (score 0):

I see the use of ‘use’ in the question ‘What did he use to call you?’, without any further explanation preceding or following, being open to interpretation as ‘what did he use to call you’; an hand-clap, a bell, a whistle etc., such as how did he get your attention.
‘What name did he use to call you’, perhaps.